# T-SQL Trigger - Audit Column Change

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers, audit

Given a simple table, with an ID what is the correct way to audit a column being changed. I am asking after looking after various answers which seem not to be working.

Here is what I have:

```sql
Create Table Tbl_Audit
(
    AuditId int identity(1,1) not null,
    Tbl_Id int not null.
    Tbl_Old_ColumnValue varchar(255),
    Tbl_New_ColumnValue varchar(255)
)

GO

Create Trigger Tr_Tbl_ColumnChanged on Tbl
after insert, update
As
begin
    if(update(ColumnName))
        begin
            insert into tbl_audit
            (
                Tbl_Id,
                Tbl_Old_ColumnName,
                Tbl_New_ColumnName
            )
            select
                tbl.PKId,
                tbl.ColumnName,
                i.ColumnName,
            from
                Tbl tbl join 
                inserted i
                on tbl.PKId = i.PKId
            
end
```

What I see is thousands of examples where `Tbl_Old_ColumnValue`  = `Tbl_New_ColumnValue` , which is not what I want.

I would expect to run:

```sql
select top 10 * from tbl_audit where Tbl_Old_ColumnValue !=Tbl_New_ColumnValue
```

But this returns no results.

In order to get results of columns that actually changed, I need to run a very expensive query:

```sql
select top 10 
old.AuditId,
old.Tbl_Old_ColumnValue,
new.Tbl_Old_ColumnValue  as [Tbl_New_ColumnValue] 
from tbl_audit [old]
join Tbl_Audit [new]
on [ol].Tbl_Id= [new].Tbl_Id and [old].AuditId != [new].AuditId
where [old].Tbl_Old_ColumnValue != [new].Tbl_Old_ColumnValue
```

Results:

```
AuditId Tbl_Id  Tbl_Old_ColumnValue Tbl_New_ColumnValue
10051       1       old_value           old_value
10052       1       new_value           new_value
```

But that doesn't produce what I expect:

```
AuditId Tbl_Id  Tbl_Old_ColumnValue Tbl_New_ColumnValue
10057       1   old_value           Some New Value
```

Oddly, If I modify the column directly via SSMS using:

```sql
update Tbl set Tbl.ColumnValue = 'Some New Value'
```

I see what I expect from my trigger:

```
AuditId Tbl_Id  Tbl_Old_ColumnValue Tbl_New_ColumnValue
10057       1   old_value           Some New Value
```

What am I doing wrong?

Also, how do I eliminate auditing of row where `update(ColumnName)` is actually false. IE, the ColumnName  (even if being set) is not audit when it is being set to the previous/old value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`update(ColumnName)` doesn't mean that the value has changed, just that that column was involved in the insert/update - and it will always be involved in an insert. You need to compare the old and new values using `inserted` and `deleted` e.g.

```
insert into tbl_audit
(
    Tbl_Id,
    Tbl_Old_ColumnName,
    Tbl_New_ColumnName
)
select
    tbl.PKId,
    tbl.ColumnName,
    i.ColumnName,
from
    inserted i
    left join deleted d on d.PKId = i.PKId
    -- Insert d.PKId is null, there are no records in deleted
    where d.PKId is null
    -- Change from null to value
    or (i.ColumnName is null and d.ColumnName is not null)
    -- Change from value to null
    or (i.ColumnName is not null and d.ColumnName is null)
    -- Change in value
    or i.ColumnName <> d.ColumnName;
```

You can potentially simplify the null check using `coalesce` and a suitable value which will never actually occur in your data.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15) is actually pretty good on all this.

And if the column is not always included in an update, then the `update(ColumnName)` test is still worth doing because it speeds up the trigger, and triggers should be as fast as possible. Personally I short circuit out early e.g. `if not update(ColumnName) return;`

Obviously you need to adapt that logic to handle all the columns you are auditing.

Comment: Deleted... hmmm? What is the significance of ````d.pkid is null```

Comment: Yes, the column is nullable

Comment: Yes, any time it gets changed, so yes, inserts. So d.pkid is null is for an insert. Got it.

Comment: Okay, so d.pkid picks up the insert then then i.columnname<>d.columnname picks up the change. So instead of querying the existing table for the current value I need to query deleted for the old value. Is that correct?

Comment: Okay, this makes sense. Documentation is not clear on updated vs deleted. But thinking of deleted as the old value certainly makes sense.

Comment: One last question. Will deleted contain all columns from the row or only those that changed? Eg, `tbl.some_other_column` that has not been changed.

Comment: Ooof! So from your answer the `if(update(ColumnName))` is no longer needed!?!?!

Comment: I'll figure it out from here. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, the column I am auditing should NEVER, EVER, EVER, EVER be updated but some Roque process likely running as a VBSCRIPT literally written before 2005 is updating the column and our entire team is trying to figure out what legacy code/task out their is updating it on us and wreaking havoc.

Comment: IE, after it first gets set from null to some value it should never change again. So my audit has lots of other columns `SUSER_NAME(), GetDate(), APP_NAME(), Host_Name(), cast(CONNECTIONPROPERTY('client_net_address') as nvarchar(128))` etc.., which I didn't include in my question.

Comment: I was actually going to edit your answer and put a link to documentation. You beat me to it.